# Extract files from a list in Excel

Tags: excel, directory, operating-system, extract

I have a list of files in excel (the list consists of 100 filenames of images), and a folder containing with 1000 images (the actual image) where in which 100 of them are on that list in excel. Based on the list in excel how can I move/copy those 100 images into a new folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a powershell script (i'm assuming you're using windows) to extract the data from the cells and then move from one path to the other. The following script should work for you with some modifications for your xlsx file names and paths.

```
$endRow= 100 #this is the last row of image locations
$col = "A"
$newPath = "C:\Users\evolve\Documents\imgFolder\"


$excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$workBook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\evolve\Documents\takeoff.xlsx")
$workSheet = $workBook.sheets.item("sheet1")


#different methods can be used to get the outcome you want.

#cycle through the rows of data
for($i = 1; $i -le $endRow; $i++)
{
    $loc = $col + $i
    $imgPath = $workSheet.Range($loc).Text
    
    #extract the actual filename
    
    $split = $imgPath.split("\")
    $imgName=[string]$split[($split.count-1)] 
    
    $newImgLocation = $newPath + $imgName
    
    #move the image to the new folder
    Move-Item $imgPath $newImgLocation
    
    
}
```